# Running mysqldump on live database

Tags: mysql

Just wanted to know what are the risks of running a mysqldump on a live database?  Are there any chances of database corruption?  mysqldump seems to lock the entire database.

Comment: This site specializes in programming questions while your question seems a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com. You might get a relevant answer faster there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What engine are your database tables using? If you are using transactional tables you can dump using the option "single-transaction", which will dump your tables in a consistent state. If you are using tables like MyISAM, which are non transactional, you should not have any DB corruption issues. You may have inconsistent data problems however, if you get into a race scenario. In either case, you will be dramatically slowing down DB response time while the dump occurs. Best bet is to run the dump against a slave or to wait for the site to be quiescent before running the dump.

Comment: I am using MyISAM for this database.  I lock out users for a 3/4 minutes when the mysqldump is running, that for now is OK.  I am more concerned with data integrity at this point.

Comment: Here's the problem you may run into. Suppose I have a database with a table "fruit" and one "shopping bag". I'm running my dump, I lock the fruit table and dump it. Suppose after that someone adds  new fruit to the fruit table, and someone puts that new fruit in their shopping bag (creates a row in the shopping_bag table which references the new fruit row). When the shopping bag gets dumped, you now have a row in it which references a fruit which does not exist! That isn't necessarily going to cause you problems... but it might, and it is inconsistent.

Comment: That is precisely what my worry is.  I have been running mysqldump for a while.  I do see inconsistencies once in a while.  I am not sure where they come from.  Mysqldump runs via cron.  So I have no way of knowing if the inconsistencies are caused by mysqldump.  I am not in a position to run a slave. I kind of assumed that the database was locked during the dump.  Is there a way of doing that, as the users cannot do anything anyway when he dump is running

Comment: Easy enough. Before you begin, DO "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK". After you finish, "UNLOCK TABLES".      http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: @rpierce I am using MySQL 5.6 and I want to know if I take a DB dump using command line while the application is running & interacting with the DB. Will it affect my system, crash the app or corrupt my data?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, it is table locking when dumping. If your DB is on the large end, and u have heavy traffic, you'll essential back traffic up. I don't think data corruption would be an issue since it locks a table before dumping the data of that table. But If I am wrong about table lock and it is a DB lock, then you essentially turned off your DB for the duration of the dumping process, but that's what queue are for, when the dumping completes, it will start executing the queue in order as they received.

Comment: I am not sure about the locking part.  It takes a 3/4 minutes to dump the database.  The blocking of users for that duration is OK for me.  But any kind of data integrity would not be acceptable.